# How to instiantiate a SystemVerilog module in a top level module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I want to use the SysWip AXI4Lite Slave verification IP (in SystemVerilog) in my top-level test-bench with my traditional *Verilog* AXI4Lite master.

Being completely new to SystemVerilog, I have problems to port-map in the toplevel testbench.

What I have: From the SysWip I have downloaded axi4lite_s_if.sv which is an *interface* and the axi4lite_s.sv which is a *package* (http://syswip.com/axi4-lite-verification-ip).
From my legacy code I have a dut_top.v and dut_top_tb.sv (I have renamed it to .sv in order to support some SV constructs - import, creating the slave class object, etc). The Verilog AXI4Lite master module is instiantiated in the dut_top.v

Target: I want to connect the ports of the legacy Verilog AXI4Lite Master to that of the SysWip VIP slave. I am getting a Syntax error message where the ports are being mapped in the dut_top_tb.sv.

So can anyone point me the proper syntax for doing the portmap for the above case?

Comment: Hi tiilic, there are 2 files provided, the interface module (axi4lite_s_if.sv) and an AXI slave (axi4lite_s.sv) to be used in the top level test-bench. So are you telling me that the classical instantiation way 'DUT DUT_inst ( .clk(sys_clk), .in(in_main),..... );' would work? And this should be done only for the interface module and not the other module?

Comment: Verilog and SystemVerilog have been rolled into each other since 2009. At the module level they work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing because you are mixing `module` and `interface` which are similar yet different constructs.

SystemVerilog interface `instance`s can be connected to SystemVerilog `module`s through interface ports. If you have a legacy Verilog module without interface ports, you can still connect an SV interface instacne to a Verilog module by using a hierarchical reference. For example

```
interface intf;
 wire w;
endinterface
module verilog_dut(input wire w);
  initial $display(w);
endmodule
module SV_dut(intf p);
  initial $display(p.w);
endmodule
module top;
  intf i1();
  verilog_dut i2(.w(i1.w));
  SV_dut i3(.p(i1));
endmodule
```

Comment: thanks for your answer and the simple illustration. I have re-framed the original question. For details look at the original question description. In simplest terms the problem I am facing right now is how to connect IN A TEST-BENCH, a classical Verilog module have ports definitions with a SystemVerilog interface? Can you plz show me some pseudo-code?